# How to generate <style> tags in Rails using Slim templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

The ["Embedded Engines" section of the official Slim docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Embedded_engines__Markdown______) claim that the using the `css`, `scss`, or `sass` filters will have Slim generate a `<style>` tag containing the described css. Their example:

```
scss class="myClass":
  $color: #f00;
  body { color: $color; }
```

> This will generate the following HTML:

```
<style class="myClass" type="text/css">body{color:red}</style>
```

When I use this example code verbatim in my template, Slim does *not* generate a `style` tag. Rather, it *applies* the styles in-line to any elements matching the written selectors. Thus:

```
scss class="myClass":
  $color: hot pink;
  body { color: $color; }

body "some text"
```

In fact generates the following HTML:

```
<body style="color: hotpink">some text</button>
```

I'm using Slim 4.0.1, slim-rails 3.2.0, and rails 5.2.2, which are all the most recently released versions of these libraries as of this writing. There are no custom configurations written that I know of.

How do I get the behavior described in the docs, wherein a `<style>` tag is generated? Is this a bug or something I'm not understanding?

Comment: Can't you find a better alternative than compiling SASS when rending the template? Even if its possible its not going to be good for performance.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are using but I got:

```html
<style class="myClass" type="text/css">body{color:red}</style></div></body></html>
```

with:

```
      scss class="myClass":
        $color: #f00;
        body { color: $color; }
```

looks like you have some kind of inliner running on your generated pages (I would check the Gemfile for the gem).